# Exit from cmd script that calls bash

Tags: windows, bash, shell, cmd, cygwin

I have the following cmd script which calls a cygwin bash script:

```
C:\cygwin\bin\bash -l /D/Temp/testScript/cygScript.sh
echo back in cmd.
exit
```

The bash script is simple:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Hello World!
read
```

The calling part works nicely - the bash shell logs in, echos as expected, reads as expected and control passes back to the cmd as expected.

But the cmd will not exit. This is fine if I run it from a command window, but I will be calling this by double clicking on the cmd file or launching it from RUN etc.

Output I see:

```
D:\Temp\testScript>C:\cygwin\bin\bash -l /D/Temp/testScript/shellScript.sh
Hello World!
D:\Temp\testScript>echo back in cmd.
back in cmd.
D:\Temp\testScript>exit
```

How do I get the cmd to exit?

### Found the problem - too many bashes

I think I found the issue - probably something in my .bashrc and other files I load during cygwin login. If I change the main cmd line to remove the login flag), it works as expected - everything closes.

```
C:\cygwin\bin\bash /D/Temp/testScript/cygScript.sh
```

But then I put the flag back:

```
C:\cygwin\bin\bash -l /D/Temp/testScript/cygScript.sh
```

and run again. I see the output `Hello World!` which shows me that control is with bash, and I check Task Manager. *Four* instances of bash.exe are created. Then I press ENTER and see the output `back in cmd.` showing me that control is back with cmd. Now Task Manager shows me that *three* bash.exe instances remain.

So, something in my login scripts are creating extra bash shells. So it's not you, it's me.

Comment: You want the cygwin terminal to close after you run your command - from double clicking a file?

Comment: No, that's not it. I edited my question to give a bit more information. The bash shell is doing it's thing and exiting. Control is going back to the cmd script and *not* exiting. The `exit` command is not doing what I expect (closing the cmd window).

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? If there is something I can do to improve it, let me know. Please don't downvote without feedback.

Comment: So by "cmd script" or "cmd file" you mean a file with `.bat` or `.cmd` extension, which you are running by double-clicking or via 'Run...'??

Comment: No repro here (Windows 7 64 bit, latest Cygwin)

Comment: OK, tried it on my work computer and the cmd closes as expected. (Win 7, 64 bit, latest Cygwin - but this is true for both my home and work PC). I wonder what the difference can be.

Comment: Please don't [edit] your question to include the answer. You should write a seperate answer - [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Thanks @DavidPostil, I honestly thought about putting this as answer, but I decided against it *because I don't know the root cause yet* (what is it in my login scripts that are creating additional bash.exe instances). I decided to report an official answer only when I figure it out. Then I think is when I have something potentially useful to future readers i.e. I am not finished yet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid creating persistent subshells in login scripts by using `cygstart` instead of `cmd`.

Previously I wrote that the problem was *too many bashes*. My `.bash_profile` was doing something to create bash sub-shells (that were persistent because the jobs they launched kept going in the background). This meant that when my `cmd` created a `bash` (via login) and the first `bash` exited, the sub-shells didn't exit.

I found that part of my login scripts involved launching some Autohotkey scripts like this:

```
cmd /c "$thePath" &
```

The fix was so easy... just use `cygstart`:

```
cygstart "$thePath"
```